# TypeScript: types that take different records

Tags: typescript

I currently model my initialising sequence with

```
    enum AuthStatus {
        Initialising,
        Authorised,
        NoAuth,
    }
```

But now I want to add the notion that, once authorised, I know whether the user is either an Admin or not.

In other words, i want to model 4 states

- Initialising
- Authorised (and in this case either an admin or not)
- NoAuth

What I want to avoid is

```
let status: AuthStatus = AuthStatus.Initialising
let isAdmin: Bool = false
```

Because that represents 6 states of which 2 are impossible

Comment: I think it worth using discriminated union with appropriate flag instead of enim

Comment: Hi, can you try to explain your scenario and problem without Elm's context? That way even people without Elm experience (like me) could understand the issue more.

Comment: changed the question

Answer (score 1):

"Discriminated union" was the clue I needed

```
    enum AuthStatus {
        Initialising,
        Authorised,
        NoAuth,
    }

    type I = {
        status: AuthStatus.Initialising
    }
    type A = {
        status: AuthStatus.Authorised,
        isAdmin: boolean
    }
    type N = {
        status: AuthStatus.NoAuth
    }

    type AuthProcess = I | A | N
```